# Attempt to index global 'cv' (a nil value)

Tags: opencv, contour, object-detection, torch, canny-operator

OS: ubuntu

I am trying to to detect edges for objects in a given image using functions from the cv package.

First, I run 'qlua' in my ubuntu terminal.

```
local cv = reuqire 'cv'
require 'cv'
reuqire 'image'
lena_p = image.load('/home/stone/codes/lena1.jpg')
image.dispaly(lena_p)
cv.rectangle{lena_p,{5,5},{10,10},color = {30,30,180},thickness = 2}
ca_l = cv.Canny{image=limg,threshold=1,threshold=10}
```

However, it fails with the following error:

> [string "cv.rectangle{lena_p,{5,5},{10,10},color = {30..."]:1: attempt to index global 'cv' (a nil value) stack traceback:  [string "cv.rectangle{lena_p,{5,5},{10,10},color = {30..."]:1: in main chunk    [C]: at 0x7f6be51eaba0
>
> [string "ca_l = cv.Canny{image=limg,threshold=1,thresh..."]:1: attempt to index global 'cv' (a nil value)
>   stack traceback:
>       [string "ca_l = cv.Canny{image=limg,threshold=1,thresh..."]:1: in main chunk
>       [C]: at 0x7feb66429ba0

My question is this, how can I use functions in the 'cv' package to detect object contour?

REF:
https://github.com/VisionLabs/torch-opencv/tree/master/cv

Comment: is this actual code? you have re**uq**ire instead of re**qu**ire

Comment: Oh! god ! my fault !  I make it correct now.  It is the actual codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing torch-cv. You can install it by executing the following command in your terminal:

```
luarocks install cv
```